# Getting react-dropzone to accept *all* files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dropzone

I have inherited a code base that is React.JS on the front-end and Node.JS/Express.JS on the back-end on an AWS EC2 instance server. The code I have usese react-dropzone (https://react-dropzone.js.org/) and was made to just take drag&drops of image files. The product owner for the project I'm working on now wants it to accept *all* files (*.pdf's, *.docx, *.xlsx, etc.).

I'm wondering how to go about getting it to accept *all* files? I've gone through the react-dropzone docs and I've yet to find any example to show how to get it to accept *all* file types? Is it as simple as setting the `accept="..."` from `accept="image/*"` to `accept="*/*"`? can the string for `accept="..."` be an array, like: `accept=["image/*","text/*",...]`, etc.? what is the correct way to get react-dropzone to accept any file type?

Here is the code for my `onDrop` callback —

```
    onDrop = (acceptedFiles, rejectedFiles) => {
      let files = acceptedFiles.map(async file => {
        let data = new FormData();
        data.append("file", file);

        let item = await axios
          .post("triage/upload", data, {
            headers: {
              "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
              "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            }
          })
          .then(response => {
            return Object.assign(file, {
              preview: URL.createObjectURL(file),
              filename: response.data.filename
            });
          })
          .catch(err => {
            let rejects = rejectedFiles.map(async file => {
              let data = new FormData();
              await data.append("file", file);

              console.log("There was an error while attempting to add your files:", err);
              console.log("The files that were rejected were:\n", rejects.join('\n'))
            })
          });
        return item;
      });
      Promise.all(files)
      .then(completed => {
        console.log("completed", completed);
        let fileNames = completed.map(function(item) {
          return item["filename"];
        });
        this.setState({ files: completed, fileNames: fileNames });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('DROPZONE ERROR:', err);
      });
    };
```

...and here is the code for `<DropZone>` itself in the same file —

```
              <Dropzone accept="image/*" onDrop={this.onDrop}>
                {({ getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive }) => {
                  return (
                    <div
                      {...getRootProps()}
                      className={classNames("dropzone", {
                        "dropzone--isActive": isDragActive
                      })}
                    >
                      <input {...getInputProps()} />
                      {isDragActive ? (
                        <div>
                          <div className="centered">
                            <Icon name="cloud upload" size="big" />
                          </div>
                          <div className="centered">Drop Files Here.</div>
                          <div className="centered">
                            <Button className="drop-button">
                              Or Click to Select
                            </Button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      ) : (
                        <div>
                          <div className="centered">
                            <Icon name="cloud upload" size="big" />
                          </div>
                          <div className="centered">
                            Drag and Drop Supporting Files here to
                            Upload.
                          </div>
                          <div className="centered">
                            <Button className="drop-button">
                              Or Click to Select
                            </Button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      )}
                    </div>
                  );
                }}
              </Dropzone>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? What happens if you simply omit the attribute?

Comment: @ChrisG - it returns an empty array (`completed ˃ []`), as in nothing got uploaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use like with regular `input`, so you can do multiple file types like: `image/*,.pdf`.

Reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#Unique_file_type_specifiers).

Comment: I'm sorry, @codecubed.io, but I don't quite know what you mean by "just use like with regular `input`," do you mean instead of `accept="image/*`, i could have `input="image/*, *.pdf, *.doc*..."` etc.?

Comment: It doesn't work for all platforms, as they say in their [documentation](https://react-dropzone.js.org/#!/Accepting%20specific%20file%20types). You can use `"video/*, image/png"`, but `".pdf, image/*"` won't let PDF documents to be accepted. Instead for pdf you need `"application/pdf"`

Comment: Reffer to the [solution](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/React-Dropzone-Component/issues/164#issuecomment-385700567)

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same issue.

`react-dropzone` uses `attr-accept` to handle accepting files. Let's look at the source code for the latter.

```
* @param file {File} https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File
 * @param acceptedFiles {string}
 * @returns {boolean}

...

export default function(file, acceptedFiles) {
  if (file && acceptedFiles) {
    ...
  }
  return true
}
```

To get a return value of `true`, simply input a falsy string value, i.e. `''`

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `accept` prop from `<Dropzone />` and it will allow any file type.

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me:

```
accept: {
    'image/jpeg': ['.jpeg', '.png'],
    'application/pdf': ['.pdf']
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. As far as I see, this won't allow the upload of Word documents or videos

Answer (score 0):

If you use useDropZone, then it will be like this

```
const {inputProps,...rest }=useDropZone({
onDrop,//onDrop function
acceptFiles:'image/png' //<--- here you provide input related info
})
```

Comment: It doesn't work for all platforms, as they say in their [documentation](https://react-dropzone.js.org/#!/Accepting%20specific%20file%20types). You can use `"video/*, image/png"`, but `".pdf, image/*"` won't let PDF documents to be accepted.